# How can we require packages in ejs templates

Tags: node.js, express

**Here is my ejs template code:**

`.<%- var fs=requires('fs'); %>`

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\views\user\user_list.ejs:3

> 1|  <%- include('../header.ejs') %>
> 2|  <%- include('../sidebar.ejs') %>
> 3|   <%-   fs=requires('fs'); %>

requires is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:16:7)
    at returnedFn (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:127:8)
    at tryRender (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\express-flash\lib\express-flash.js:29:16)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\controllers\user_controller.js:10:16
```

Comment: here is my code <%- include('../header.ejs') %>
 <%- include('../sidebar.ejs') %>
  <%-   fs=requires('fs'); %>

Comment: Error is : ReferenceError: C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\views\user\user_list.ejs:3
    1|  <%- include('../header.ejs') %>

    2|  <%- include('../sidebar.ejs') %>

 >> 3|   <%-   fs=requires('fs'); %>

  

requires is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\Nodejs\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:16:7)
    at returnedFn

Comment: You may have misunderstood what templates are for and how they work. Anything you need, you "template into them" so that the placeholders are substituted with real data. You don't require libraries into them, you write them as if they're normal HTML files, with placeholders for "data that will get generated before sending the file in response to an request". Hit up https://www.ejs.co again, and refresh your memory on how you're supposed to use them.